# How xsl will work when "xmlns" attribute exist in a node of xml

Tags: xslt

My xsl is working fine when "xmlns" attribute doesn't exist in a node integration_test_results of xml. What i can do in xsl so it will work when "xmlns" attribute exist in integration_test_results node.

Please help me ASAP.

Here i am attaching my xml and xsl file:

Attach xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="framework_results.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>
<integration_test_results xmlns="http://schemas.oracle.com/dm/v2009">
    <test>
        <name>Reg_Table_test_1</name>
        <status>PASSED</status>
        <start_time>2010-10-19 05:04:58.011</start_time>
        <finish_time>2010-10-19 05:07:29.779</finish_time>
        <test_duration>0</test_duration>
        <datamover_job>
            <status>COMPLETED_SUCCESSFUL</status>
            <start_time>2010-10-19 05:04:58.011</start_time>
            <finish_time>2010-10-19 05:07:29.779</finish_time>
            <job_duration>0</job_duration>
        </datamover_job>
    </test>
</integration_test_results>
```

Attach xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
 xmlns:ns="http://schemas.oracle.com/dm/v2009">

 <xsl:template match="ns:integration_test_results">
 <html>
 <body>
  <h2 align="center">Test Report</h2>
  <table border="1" align="center">
   <tr bgcolor="orange">
    <Th colspan="2">Results </Th> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <th align="Left" bgcolor="orange">Tests passed/Failed/Skipped:</th>
    <td>
     <xsl:value-of select="count(test[status='PASSED'])" /> &#47;
     <xsl:value-of select="count(test[status='FAILED'])" /> &#47;
     <xsl:value-of select="count(test[status='RUNNING'])" /> 
    </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <th align="Left" bgcolor="orange">Started on:</th>
    <xsl:for-each select="test">
    <xsl:sort select="start_time" order="ascending" data-type="text" />
    <xsl:if test="position()=1">
    <TD>
     <xsl:value-of select="start_time" />
    </TD>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <th align="Left" bgcolor="orange">Total time:</th> 
    <td>
     <xsl:value-of select="sum(test/test_duration[number(.)=number(.)])" /> 
    </td>

   </tr>
   <tr>
    <th align="Left" bgcolor="orange">Included groups:</th>
    <td>
     <!-- <xsl:value-of select="" /> -->
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <th align="Left" bgcolor="orange">Excluded groups:</th>
    <td>
     <!-- <xsl:value-of select="" /> -->
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <br></br>
  <table border="1">
   <tr bgcolor="orange">
    <th rowspan="2">Test Name</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Test Results</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Start Time(sec)</th>
    <th rowspan="2">End Time(sec)</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Test Duration(sec)</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Message</th>
    <th colspan="5">DM JOB</th>

   </tr>
   <tr bgcolor="orange">
    <th>Job Name</th>
    <th>Job Results</th>
    <th>Start Time(sec)</th>
    <th>End Time(sec)</th>
    <th>Job Duration(sec)</th>
   </tr>
   <xsl:for-each select="test">
   <xsl:sort select="start_time" order="ascending" data-type="text" />
   <tr>
    <td>
     <xsl:value-of select="name" />
    </td>
    <td>
     <xsl:value-of select="status"/>
    </td>
    <td>
     <xsl:value-of select="start_time" />
    </td> 
    <td>
     <xsl:value-of select="finish_time" />
    </td>
    <td>
     <xsl:value-of select="test_duration"/>
    </td>
    <td>
     <xsl:value-of select="message" />
    </td> 
    <xsl:for-each select="datamover_job">
     <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="name" />
     </td>
     <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="status"/>
     </td>
     <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="start_time" />
     </td> 
     <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="finish_time" />
     </td>     
     <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="job_duration"/>
     </td>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </tr>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
 </body>
 </html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

--Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, properly speaking, there is no `xmlns` attribute: this is a namespace declaration.

Second, you have an inconsistent way to deal with namespaces in your stylesheet's XPath expression: you have matched the root element with the proper namespace `ns:integration_test_results` but after that you no longer select it descendants with that namespace.

This is FAQ: Namespace declarations get propagate to descendants.

Answer (score 0):

Try prefixing the rest of the elements just you prefixed

```
match="ns:integration_test_results"
```

In the xml you have the default namespace. In the xsl you bind a prefix ns to the same namespace. Therefore, you need to prefix the rest of the elements.

Here is a partial change. Sorry I don't have time to do the rest, but you can figure it out yourself..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns="http://schemas.oracle.com/dm/v2009">
<xsl:template match="ns:integration_test_results">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2 align="center">Test Report</h2>
            <table border="1" align="center">
                <tr bgcolor="orange">
                    <Th colspan="2">Results </Th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th align="Left" bgcolor="orange">Tests passed/Failed/Skipped:</th>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="count(ns:test[ns:status='PASSED'])"/> &#47;
 <xsl:value-of select="count(ns:test[ns:status='FAILED'])"/> &#47;
 <xsl:value-of select="count(ns:test[ns:status='RUNNING'])"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th align="Left" bgcolor="orange">Started on:</th>
                    <xsl:for-each select="ns:test">
                        <xsl:sort select="ns:start_time" order="ascending" data-type="text"/>
                        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                            <TD>
                                <xsl:value-of select="ns:start_time"/>
                            </TD>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th align="Left" bgcolor="orange">Total time:</th>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="sum(/ns:test/ns:test_duration[number(.)=number(.)])"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th align="Left" bgcolor="orange">Included groups:</th>
                    <td>
                        <!-- <xsl:value-of select="" /> -->
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th align="Left" bgcolor="orange">Excluded groups:</th>
                    <td>
                        <!-- <xsl:value-of select="" /> -->
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br/>
            <table border="1">
                <tr bgcolor="orange">
                    <th rowspan="2">Test Name</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">Test Results</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">Start Time(sec)</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">End Time(sec)</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">Test Duration(sec)</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">Message</th>
                    <th colspan="5">DM JOB</th>
                </tr>
                <tr bgcolor="orange">
                    <th>Job Name</th>
                    <th>Job Results</th>
                    <th>Start Time(sec)</th>
                    <th>End Time(sec)</th>
                    <th>Job Duration(sec)</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="ns:test">
                    <xsl:sort select="ns:start_time" order="ascending" data-type="text"/>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="ns:name"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="ns:status"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="ns:start_time"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="ns:finish_time"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="ns:test_duration"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="ns:message"/>
                        </td>
                        <xsl:for-each select="ns:datamover_job">
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="ns:name"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="ns:status"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="ns:start_time"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="ns:finish_time"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="ns:job_duration"/>
                            </td>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```